# get the description field of a sitefinity classification in code

Tags: c#, telerik, sitefinity

I am new to sitefinity, I am looking for a way to the access the description field of the classification in my code.

Please let me know how I can do that.

I have written code that gets me all the classifications(hierarchial taxonomy) in the form of a tree that I am binding to a RadTreeView control.

Each node in the RadTreeView control has properties like text, navigateURL etc. but no Description. I assume I have to do it differently to get the description field.

Any help or direction is appreciated. It looks to me like a very basic implementation to get the description but not able to get it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a function that uses the Sitefinity API to look up a Category by Title.

You'll need the following using statements:

```
using Telerik.Sitefinity.Taxonomies;
using Telerik.Sitefinity.Taxonomies.Model;
```

I've added the line that gets the description to hopefully better answer your question.

```
private Taxon GetCategoryByTitle(string category)
{
    var manager = TaxonomyManager.GetManager();
    var categoriesTaxa = manager.GetTaxonomy<HierarchicalTaxonomy>(TaxonomyManager.CategoriesTaxonomyId);

    var taxomony = categoriesTaxa.Taxa.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Title == category);

    var description = taxomony.Description; //get description here

    return taxomony;
}
```